# How to get the meeting request that a meeting response responds to?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to access the meeting request a meeting response is responding to when the meeting response is about to be sent:

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.ItemSend += Application_ItemSend;
}

private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
    var meeting = Item as Outlook.MeetingItem;
    if (meeting == null) return;
    if (meeting.MessageClass == MeetingMessageClasses.Declined || meeting.MessageClass == MeetingMessageClasses.Accepted || meeting.MessageClass == MeetingMessageClasses.Tentative)
    {
        var meetingRequest = GetMeetingRequest(meeting);
    }
}

Outlook.MeetingItem GetMeetingRequest(Outlook.MeetingItem meetingResponse)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException("Please help me to implement this");
}
```

I have these constants:

```
public static class MeetingMessageClasses
{
    public const string Canceled = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Canceled";
    public const string Request = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Request";
    public const string Declined = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Neg";
    public const string Accepted = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Pos";
    public const string Tentative = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Resp.Tent";
    public const string Forward = "IPM.Schedule.Meeting.Notification.Forward";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use MeetingItem.GetAssociatedAppointment - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867189.aspx

Comment: I don't want to get the associated appointment, I need to get the meeting request. Additionally, if you decline the meeting request the appointment is deleted so you cannot access it.

Comment: Once processed, a meeting request is deleted by Outlook.